# What is the etymology of the Scythian word "hezios" meaning "covered"?

Tags: etymology, history, plinius-maior

Pliny the Elder claimed, in the 6th book in the 19th chapter of "Naturalis Historia", that the name "Caucasus" comes from Scythian "kroi hezios" meaning "snow-covered". The word "kroi" (presumably meaning "snow") is probably cognate to Greek κρυος (ice). But where would the Scythian word "hezios" meaning "covered" come from?

EDIT: In case there is any ambiguity, I am not implying Pliny's etymology was right. But I think it is relatively reasonable to believe "kroi hezios" really meant "snow-covered" in Scythian.

Comment: [Pliny](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0138%3Abook%3D6%3Achapter%3D21) said: "scythae ipsi persas chorsaros et caucasum montem **croucasim**, hoc est **nive candidum**, [appellavere]." That would be _white with snow_, rather than _snow-covered_. Do you have a source the backs up the claim that it's from "kroi hezios"?

Comment: Probably unknown, since Etymonline doesn't elaborate, but you might get a better answer with linguists who specialize in Indo-Iranian languages: https://www.etymonline.com/word/Caucasus#etymonline_v_27825

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%9A%CE%B1%CF%8D%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) says "Perhaps from Proto-Scythian *xrohukäsi (“ice-shining, white with snow”)."